# Raising specific exception python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have many exceptions in my exceptions.py file. And, I have one parent exception:

```
class MainError(Exception):

        def __init__(self, msg, function_name, result):
            super(ApiException, self).__init__("Error: . {0}".format(msg))
            self.function_name = function_name
            self.result = result
```

Before, I was raising only main exception. Now, I think it is better to make exception for each error, so I created exceptions in exceptions.py file.

Example of child exception:

```
class SomeError(MainError):
    _match = 'Forbidden'
```

I have such exceptions, with different _match variable. So, I need to match description of error, and raise an exception that fits to description.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you add more details, please? Other exceptions and how you raised them.

Comment: I edited, can you check?

Comment: @deceze, can you reopen the question please. The OP edited it content.

Comment: If you raise the exception `SomeError` it's because you already know it's `Forbidden`. I don't understand what you want to do. How do you raise exception? `raise SomeError()`?

Comment: I am using API. It gives response. I have a method to get updates from API, and I am raising MainError if result is not 'ok'. So, now I need to add exceptions, but checking exception with if-else won't be a good idea.

Comment: While you can maybe go through your defined exceptions programmatically and match them somehow, it's probably a better idea to make that more explicit. If you have a lot of different exceptions, *map* them: `raise {'Forbidden': SomeException, ...}.get(error, MainException)(error, f, r)`